# Intermittent reference (bibliography) in Latex

Tags: latex, bibliography, miktex, texstudio

I have TexStudio and MikTex to edit Latex files on my PC versions 4.0.3 and 4.4, respectively. However, my bibfiles references work in an randomly way: sometimes they're recognized, in others, they are not.

Minimal Reproducible Example

```
\documentclass[msc]{ppgccufmg}

\begin{document}
    
Testing the reference \cite{COAF}
    
\ppgccbibliography{bibfile}

\end{document}
```

Bibfile.bib

```
@misc{COAF,
    title = {O que é lavagem de dinheiro e financiamento do terrorismo},
    howpublished = {\url{https://www.gov.br/coaf/pt-br/pastas-antigas-disponiveis-para-pesquisa/o-sistema-de-prevencao-a-lavagem-de-dinheiro/o-que-e-o-crime-de-lavagem-de-dinheiro-ld}},
    note = {Accessed: 2010-09-30}
}
```

Class ppgccufmg: https://github.com/verlab/ppgccufmg
(Delete \RequirePackage{etextools} in line 40)

Error:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Two problems:

- latex ignores everything after `\end{document}`, if you want a bibliography, you must place it before it
- you are using `\url{...}` in your .bib file. You need to load a package like `hyperref` or `url` which defines this macro

---

```
\documentclass[msc]{ppgccufmg}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
    
Testing the reference \cite{COAF}

\ppgccbibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The bibliography after the \end{document} was really my mistake while building the minimal reproducible example. I've just fixed. It worked perfectly. Thank you very much!

Comment: @CláudioAlmeida You're welcome!